# Kibana 4 Unable to load "text!config" modules because of an unknown error

Tags: apache, nginx, elasticsearch, kibana-4

When going to localhost/kibana4/ I get the following errors:

- Error: Unable to load "text!config" modules because of an unknown error.
  text.get/xhr.onreadystatechange@localhost/kibana4/index.js?_b=6004:45303:31
- Error: Error: Unable to load "text!config" modules because of an unknown error. (:0)
  window.onerror@localhost/kibana4/index.js?_b=6004:45829:24

I have done some searching, but all I could find were people using nginx. The fix should be adding **proxy_set_header Host $http_host;** to location /.

Since I'm not using nginx but apache, I wouldn't have a clue how to fix it. I did some research on how to add these kinds of things to apache, but no solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Sources used:

- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2814
- https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1630

EDIT: This was on a docker container. Now I switched to a new container and not receiving this error anymore.